# 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as our backup questions for a total of 8 questions - I ended up merging one of the submitted with a backup question due to proximity of the topics covered.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/695d761f-f398-443e-992e-d0712ff0a380/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

---

> 1. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 2. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 3. Are there any current moderator practices you would like to see changed? Are there any things you would do differently?
> 4. How do you plan to handle flags on comments? Generally speaking, should comments that are obsolete or resolved be deleted, or should they be kept around to preserve the history of the conversation? Should back-and-forth discussion in the comments be deleted, moved to chat, or retained?
> 5. What is your stance on migration from and to [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com), respectively?
> 6. Why do you think you would make a good moderator for this site? In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 7. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 8. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: Guys, We need more candidates. Please nominate yourself :)

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany  I'll vote for you!